# why i am unable to make any request to my mongodb database from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying make post request from nodejs api to mongodb it is not working neither it is showing any error.

Before trying this my mongodb server was not working so i installed it again after uninstalling it. Right now mongo is connected fine even my nodejs console says that database is connected.

I am trying make post request using `postsman`.

I do have installed mongoose, body-parser and express. 
I am unable to figure out what is wrong here. please help.

this is my code

> routes/posts.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new Post({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        title: req.body.title,
        overview: req.body.overview,
        content: req.body.content,
    })
    post.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Post created",
            createdPost: {
                _id: result._id,
                title: result.title,
                overview: result.overview,
                content: result.content,
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

> model/Post.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    overview: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

},{timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postschema);
```

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const posts = require('./routes/posts');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/adi-site', { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
    () => { console.log('database is connected') },
    err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err) }
);


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('api/posts', posts);

app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log('App is on 8080'))
```

> This is how i am posting using postman

[image: nodejserror]

Comment: How do you know it does not work ? what happenss ?

Comment: postman gives this response `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /api/posts</pre>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @nos `postman` is not giving response as excepted.

Comment: I think you should post whole routing code and the body parser configurations

Comment: Is that console.log(result) return expected value?

Comment: @viz i have updated my question have a look

Comment: @Dilshan it returns noting

Comment: Oh postman says, Cannot POST /api/posts . You are posting to the wrong router. I'm pretty much sure /api/posts is a GET route. Above router is just '/'

Comment: @Dilshan  in index.js I have added this line `app.use('api/posts', posts);` i think this make route as `localhost:8080/api/posts/` am i right ?

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't saw that you are using app.use('api/posts' , posts)

Comment: @Dilshan its okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192149/discussion-between-dilshan-and-aditya-kumar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your route is not getting called. Why? because you never send a request to it. POSTMAN says cannot POST /api/posts . I think it is because you use

```
app.use('api/posts',  posts)
```

I think this should be the correct way

```
app.use('/api/posts' , posts)
```

Comment: yeah that's for sure.